# How to use jspdf with google maps

Tags: google-maps, jspdf

I am using jspdf to convert a html page to pdf. My page has a google map displayed on it. 
I am confused as to how to display that map on the pdf. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the new **addHTML()** function.

This function will canvas the HTML DOM (In your case a DIV) and convert it to an Image using anopther library called [*html2canvas*](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and add that image (in you case the Google Map) to your PDF.

Example codes are available in [GitHub](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/js/html2canvas.js).

Or alternatively you can attach an image of your Google map (if it points out a stable place) to your PDF.